# GPU - Black Screen when running Tensorflow on Python3.5 in Windows 8.1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Followed instructions on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows
When I get to

activate tensorflow-gpu
$ python

import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
Screen goes Black. When I move the cursor it moves, and then resets to the center every 10 seconds or so and disappears into the blackness, and doesnt go back to normal screen.
System information

Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit

used pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Cuda toolkit 8.0

Cudnn 5.1

intel i7-4700HQ

4G NVidia GT 750M:

python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.GIT_VERSION, tf.VERSION)"
b'unkown' 1.1.0

//
I then tried : 
www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth
both the allow growth and limiting gpu memory fraction until 0.1, but still getting black screen. I was suggested there are driver or GPU issues.

Let me know what else I should provide

Answer (score 1):

I've got exactly same problem. Very similar hardware and software:

My data:

Cuda toolkit 8.0

Cudnn 5.1

intel i7-4500U

NVidia GT 730M

Problem:

Black screen with cursor visible after running Python + Tensorflow.

**Solution:**

Updated NVidia Display Drivers to the latest.

Worked flawlessly.

I think drivers must be updated after Cuda toolkit + Cudnn is installed.

Good luck!